# If $X$ and $Y$ are finite, then $ X \times Y $ is finite, and $ | X \times Y | = |X|\cdot |Y| $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

(I realized that a very similar question has been asked before but it wasn't helpful). Well, I need to prove: If $X$ and $Y$ are finite, then $ X \times Y $ is finite, and $ | X \times Y | = |X|\cdot |Y| $

So I would like to know if what I've done so far is correct (any improvements are welcome):

1. To prove that $ X \times Y $ is finite I proved that $ X \times Y \subseteq \wp (\wp (X \cup Y ))$. For that I show that $ X \cup Y $ is finite using the lemma 2.6 (Introduction to set theory. Jech, Hrbacek. Chapter 4. Section 2) and then I used the theorem 2.8 (Introduction to set theory. Jech, Hrbacek. Chapter 4. Section 2) to show that $ \wp (\wp (X \cup Y ))$ is finite. Then, using the definition of cartesian product $ X \times Y \subseteq \wp (\wp (X \cup Y ))$ and so $ X \times Y $ is finite for the theorem 2.4 (Introduction to set theory. Jech, Hrbacek. Chapter 4. Section 2).
2. To prove this: $ | X \times Y | = |X|\cdot |Y| $ I need to define a function  that is bijective, but I'm having trouble defining such function.

I would appreciate some ideas for it.

Comment: If you show $| X \times Y| = |X| \cdot |Y|$ with $X$ and $Y$ finite then $X \times Y$ is finite so you only need to consider your point 2. However I'm a bit confused by the task of seeking a bijective function. Why don't you look at this problem *combinatorially*. Isn't it obvious how many elements the set $X \times Y$ has (for finite X and Y) by just looking at its very definition?

Comment: Isn't that $|X| \cdot |Y| = | X \times Y|$ is the very definition of $|X| \cdot |Y|$? What we have to prove is only that this definition is legitimate. For this we need to prove that "If $A, B, A', B'$ are such that $|A|=|A'|,|B|=|B'|$, then $|A \times B|=|A' \times B'|$"